# Como fazer uma paralelismo ou chamada assíncrona em uma lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho essa query

```
qry.ForEach(q =>
            {
                var product = new Product();

                product.CategoryId = q.CategoryId;
                product.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration;
                product.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration;
                product.HaveMaximumPercentage = q.HaveMaximumPercentage;
                product.HaveMinimumPercentage = q.HaveMinimumPercentage;
                product.Hidden = q.Hidden;
                product.ChildrenCategoryId = q.ChildrenCategoryId;
                product.Description = q.Description;
                product.DistributionCenterErpId = q.DistributionCenterErpId;
                product.MaximumPercentage = q.MaximumPercentage;
                product.MinimumPercentage = q.MinimumPercentage;
                product.Name = q.Name;
                product.NameHtml = q.NameHtml;
                product.Order = q.Order;
                product.PartNumber = q.PartNumber;
                product.PictureId = q.PictureId;
                product.ShortDescription = q.ShortDescription;
                product.StandardMarkup = q.StandardMarkup;

                //if (product.PictureId.HasValue)
                //    q.PictureFilename = product.Picture.FileName;

                //var pct = product.PictureId.Value > 0 ? q.PictureFilename = product.Picture.FileName : "";

                var parentProducts = _productService.GetParentsOf(product.Id).Select(x => x.PartNumber);
                q.Parents.AddRange(parentProducts);

                var price = _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId).Result;

                if (price.BasePriceUSD > 0)
                    q.DolarRate = price.BasePriceBRL / price.BasePriceUSD;

                q.ResellerPriceUSD = price.ResellerPriceUSD;
                q.ResellerPriceBRL = price.ResellerPriceBRL;
                q.BasePriceBRL = price.BasePriceBRL;
                q.BasePriceUSD = price.BasePriceUSD;

            });
```

Nessa linha a performance está ruim

```
var price = _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId).Result;
```

Isso se dá, porque como podem ver, para cada item de produto, é realizada essa chamada. Essa chamada é um serviço, que vai ao banco pega os valores de cada item e devolve. Essa ida é demorada. Se uma passada dessa, levar 10s, por exemplo, em 202 itens eu teria 2020 segundos, o que mata a execução de todo o sistema. Vocês que são bons nisso, existe uma forma, paralela, assíncrona ou de outra forma, para minimizar esse impacto que é muito grande. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

O que eu quero, para ser direto, é como eu contorno esse problema, na linha citada, para melhorar o desempenho

Comment: Precisa do objeto todo para obter o preço? Ou apenas de uma chave? Pergunto porque provavelmente conseguiria obter o preço para todos os produtos antes de entrar nesse `ForEach`.

Answer (score 1):

Existe sempre a possibilidade de utilizar o `Parallel.ForEach` ([How to: Write a simple Parallel.ForEach loop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// ...

Parallel.ForEach(qry, (q) =>
{
    var product = new Product()
    {
        CategoryId = q.CategoryId,
        AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration,
        AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration,
        HaveMaximumPercentage = q.HaveMaximumPercentage,
        HaveMinimumPercentage = q.HaveMinimumPercentage,
        Hidden = q.Hidden,
        ChildrenCategoryId = q.ChildrenCategoryId,
        Description = q.Description,
        DistributionCenterErpId = q.DistributionCenterErpId,
        MaximumPercentage = q.MaximumPercentage,
        MinimumPercentage = q.MinimumPercentage,
        Name = q.Name,
        NameHtml = q.NameHtml,
        Order = q.Order,
        PartNumber = q.PartNumber,
        PictureId = q.PictureId,
        ShortDescription = q.ShortDescription,
        StandardMarkup = q.StandardMarkup
    };

    var parentProducts = _productService.GetParentsOf(product.Id).Select(x => x.PartNumber);

    q.Parents.AddRange(parentProducts);

    var price = _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId).Result;

    if (price.BasePriceUSD > 0)
        q.DolarRate = price.BasePriceBRL / price.BasePriceUSD;

    q.ResellerPriceUSD = price.ResellerPriceUSD;
    q.ResellerPriceBRL = price.ResellerPriceBRL;
    q.BasePriceBRL = price.BasePriceBRL;
    q.BasePriceUSD = price.BasePriceUSD;
});
```

Basicamente é criada uma Thread para cada registo e é tudo feito paralelamente, mas não sei se será a solução mais "correta".

---

Outra solução seria criar um método `GetPrice` que recebesse uma lista de `IDs` de produtos (visto que o 2º e 3º parâmetros são estáticos dentro do ciclo), onde depois para cada instância do objeto `qry` atualizasse o que fosse necessário.

Essa, se calhar, seria a opção menos "pesada", não se criam inumeras *threads* e é capaz de ser mais *performante* do que a 1ª opção.

Comment: João, quanto a ganhar performance com o Paralell eu não consegui. O problema está exatamente nessa instrução: `var price = _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId).Result;`. Essa chamada a esse serviço, está sendo realizada várias vezes e eu ainda não consegui resolver isso. Qualquer ajuda é muito bem vinda

Comment: Então aí eu iria para a minha proposta 2ª solução!

Comment: Então, o problema é que é uma chamada a um serviço que está dentro do Protheus e eu não tenho acesso. Posso criar métodos, mas dentro desse serviço eu tenho apenas um método que traz o preço, `RetornaPreco` onde eu passo um **objeto produto, quantidade, o id da revenda/usuário**. De qualquer forma para eu trazer tudo de uma vez, dentro de uma lambda, por exemplo, teria que criar um loop para ir passando cada item do produto e a quantidade, ainda que estática(1), certo, ou teria uma outra forma mais inteligente que isso?

Answer (score 1):

Faça uso do método [Task.WhenAll](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2), uma alternativa, provavelmente mais recomendada de se lidar com paralelismo.

Uma maneira de reformular este código para executar paralelamente é assim (removi o excesso de código para focar na resposta):

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

qry.ForEach(q =>
            {
                var product = new Product();

                // atribuições

                var parentProductsTask = Task.Run(() => 
                {
                    var parentProducts = _productService.GetParentsOf(product.Id).Select(x => x.PartNumber);
                    q.Parents.AddRange(parentProducts);
                });

                var priceTask = Task.Run(() => 
                {
                    var price = _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId).Result;

                    if (price.BasePriceUSD > 0)
                        q.DolarRate = price.BasePriceBRL / price.BasePriceUSD;

                    q.ResellerPriceUSD = price.ResellerPriceUSD;
                    q.ResellerPriceBRL = price.ResellerPriceBRL;
                    q.BasePriceBRL = price.BasePriceBRL;
                    q.BasePriceUSD = price.BasePriceUSD;
                });

                tasks.Add(parentProductsTask);
                tasks.Add(priceTask);
            });

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Daskpark, após o bloco da ***qry*** eu coloquei isso `var model = new CatalogResponse();
            model.CatalogDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            model.Items = new List<CatalogItemResponse>();
            model.Items.AddRange(qry);`, como ficaria com o Task agora.